# executing command using ssh.net long text how parse this backspaces?

Tags: c#, shell, ssh.net

I have some large project that connect to many devices over `SSH.NET`

i have some issue that when i do `shells.Read()` and output have some long line i get output like

```
"description <XC descritption long , id123123123 IP:120.120.120.20 VC\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b$ <XC descritption long, id123123123  IP:120.120.120.20 VCI         \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bD:2500\r\ndescription <XC descritption long, id123123123  IP:120.120.120.20 VCID:2500\r\n  ^\r\n% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.\r\n\r\ngateway2#"
```

i googled a little and found that it  is some way of sending long lines to output if it does not fit inside one line of this 'virtual terminal window' ?

my question is **how to parse it programaticly** without any actual textbox that would do this automaticly so i get what i should so only

```
 description <XC descritption long, id123123123  IP:120.120.120.20 VCID:2500\r\n  ^\r\n% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.\r\n\r\ngateway2#"
```

?
i would need to count this `\b` and do some cutting based of numbers of them ? or is it some 'proper' way to do this ?

thanks and regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the backspaces and remove the preceding character (if it exists).

I'd use a method along the lines of the following:

```
public static string ParseBackspaces(string input)
{
    List<char> characters = new List<char>(input);
    int index = 0;
    while (index < characters.Count)
    {
        int back1 = index - 1;
        if (back1 >= 0 && characters[index] == '\b')
        {
            characters.RemoveRange(back1, 2);
            index = back1;
            continue;
        }
        else if (characters[index] == '\b')
        {
            characters.RemoveAt(index);
            continue;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return new String(characters.ToArray());
}
```

Here's a fiddle showing your string once parsed by this method: https://dotnetfiddle.net/79U8sH

Comment: thanks - easiest solutions are best ! i tried to catch all at once and that was my mistake ;D